# Disassociated questions appearing in bounty section on profile

Tags: support, profile-page, bounty, disassociation

A while back, I asked some of my questions to be disassociated from my profile. Some of these questions had bounties on.

I've just had a look in the bounty section on my profile and noticed that the anonymous questions are still appearing there.

Is this a bug or are bounty questions that are now anonymous meant to appear on the user's profile?

Take this question for example: [Add hyperlinks to SWF buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40259183/add-hyperlinks-to-swf-buttons) - it is annonymous but appears on my [bounty page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5798798/the-codesee?tab=bounties):

[image]

Comment: You have put a bounty on the question. That doesn't (necessarily) mean that you posted the question. Users can offer bounties to any question that they see fit, not just their own.

Comment: @VLAZ Ah that explains it. Thanks.